# Why the best model is the one with the smallest R squared? Ridge Regression

Tags: regression, cross-validation, r-squared, ridge-regression, model-evaluation

This is my example in Python. As you can see, RidgeCV, which performs cross-validation and picks the best alpha to use, picks the model with the smallest R squared as the best model... Why?

This is my `X`:

```
 X =  np.array([[  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   5.,   4.,   0.,   2.,   5.,  11.,
              3.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  13.,
              4.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   4.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  12.,
              2.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   4.,   5.,  12.,
              4.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  12.,
              5.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   2.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  13.,
              3.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   2.,   4.,   0.,   4.,   5.,  11.,
              4.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   2.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  11.,
              5.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  12.,
              5.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  12.,
              5.,  19.,   2.]])
```

and this is my response `y`

```
y = np.array([ 70.14963195,  70.20937046,  70.20890363,  70.14310389,
        70.18076206,  70.13179977,  70.13536797,  70.10700998,
        70.09194074,  70.09958111])
```

**Ridge Regression**

```
    # alpha = 0.1
    model = Ridge(alpha = 0.1)
    model.fit(X,y)
    model.score(X,y)   # gives 0.36898424479816627

    # alpha = 0.01
    model1 = Ridge(alpha = 0.01)
    model1.fit(X,y)
    model1.score(X,y)     # gives 0.3690347045143918 > 0.36898424479816627

    # alpha = 0.001
    model2 = Ridge(alpha = 0.001)
    model2.fit(X,y)
    model2.score(X,y)  #gives 0.36903522192901728 > 0.3690347045143918

    # alpha = 0.0001
    model3 = Ridge(alpha = 0.0001)
    model3.fit(X,y)
    model3.score(X,y)  # gives 0.36903522711624259 > 0.36903522192901728
```

Thus from here it should be clear that `alpha = 0.0001` is the best option. Indeed reading the documentation it says that the score is the coefficient of determination. If the coefficient closest to 1 describes the best model. Now let's see what `RidgeCV` tells us

**RidgeCV regression**

```
modelCV = RidgeCV(alphas = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001,0.0001], store_cv_values = True)
modelCV.fit(X,y)
modelCV.alpha_  #giving 0.1
modelCV.score(X,y)  # giving 0.36898424479812919 which is the same score as ridge regression with alpha = 0.1
```

What is going wrong? Surely we can check manually, as I have done, that all the other alphas are better. So not only it is not choosing the best alpha, but it is choosing the worst!

Can someone explain to me what it's going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the `modelCV.score` is value of the fit on the whole data but the actual CV fold scores are different (and possibly not shown)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What went wrong? You're comparing apples with oranges

- You computed *training* scores, meaning you scored the model on data you trained it with. You should compute *test* scores, i.e. a score on data the model has not yet seen.
- The manual check you did is just *one* experiment. If you repeat this several times with different $X$ and $y$, you will find `model.score` to give different values each time. Since you did only one experiment, i.e. used only one X and one y, your manual check is not very robust.
- Therefore, **your manual check produces a one-sample training score**.

RidgeCV is doing something more robust:

1. It takes the $X$ and $y$ you provided, splits them into 3 parts
2. It internally does `model.fit` on the first 2 parts and then `model.score` on the 3rd part, a test score.
3. It repeats step 2, but doing `model.fit` on part 2 and 3, then `model.score` on part 1
4. It repeats step 2 again, but doing `model.fit`on part 3 and 1, then `model.score` on part 2
5. Finally it averages the `model.score` values from the three steps before, this is what it returns as `modelCV.score`. That means, **RidgeCV produces an averaged test score**.

The above steps are repeated for all alphas you provide. Each alpha produces such an average.

The above process is called 3-fold cross validation, you can read more about it on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) or the [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

Comment: Thank you, super clear explanation! Realized only now! SO basically to make real comparisons, I should have checked cross-validation for all four alphas manually, and only then I would have found the same result as `RidgeCV`?

Comment: Also, Ridge CV seems to be giving R^2 (also, why do people provide R^2 and not adjR^2?) with `model.score(x,y)`. I also could compute RMSE. If my goal is see how well the models can predict, should I use RMSE right? Or should stick with the R^2?

Comment: You should decide what is more useful to you. If you're interested in the average prediction error, then RMSE on the test set is interesting. If you're more interested in knowing how much of the variance in the data your model captures, you should go with R^2. Why sklearn uses R^2 by default is not known to me, but my guess would be because it's more common and simpler to compute.